# python Pathlib, how do I remove leading directories to get relative paths?

Tags: python, path

Let's say I have this directory structure.

```
├── root1
│   └── root2
│       ├── bar
│       │   └── file1
│       ├── foo
│       │   ├── file2
│       │   └── file3
│       └── zoom
│           └── z1
│               └── file41
```

I want to isolate path components relative to `root1/root2`, i.e. strip out the leading `root` part, giving relative directories:

```
  bar/file1
  foo/file3
  zoom/z1/file41
```

The root depth can be arbitrary and the files, the node of this tree, can also reside at different levels.

This code does it, but I am looking for Pathlib's pythonic way to do it.

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

#these would come from os.walk or some glob...
file1 = Path("root1/root2/bar/file1")
file2 = Path("root1/root2/foo/file3")
file41 = Path("root1/root2/zoom/z1/file41")

root = Path("root1/root2")

#take out the root prefix by string replacement.
for file_ in [file1, file2, file41]:

    #is there a PathLib way to do this?
    file_relative = Path(str(file_).replace(str(root),"").lstrip(os.path.sep))
    print("  %s" % (file_relative))
```

Comment: Is `file_.relative_to(root)` what you're looking for?

Comment: yes, I just found it as well. if you put it in, I'll accept it.

Comment: @hurlenko if you haven't started, i might delete the question too, as it does seem like a duplicate.

Comment: well, you decide

Comment: you wrote it, so I'll accept.  I did look for related questions and they did not show up, so it can't hurt too much to have another reference to `relative_to`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

TLDR: use [Path.relative_to](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.relative_to):

```py
Path("a/b/c").relative_to("a/b")  # returns PosixPath('c')
```

Full example:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import os

# these would come from os.walk or some glob...
file1 = Path("root1/root2/bar/file1")
file2 = Path("root1/root2/foo/file3")
file41 = Path("root1/root2/zoom/z1/file41")

root = Path("root1/root2")

# take out the root prefix by string replacement.
for file_ in [file1, file2, file41]:

    # is there a PathLib way to do this?
    file_relative = file_.relative_to(root)
    print("  %s" % (file_relative))
```

Prints

```
  bar\file1
  foo\file3
  zoom\z1\file41
```

Comment: that's great! I also found `os.path.relpath` makes similar thing.